# Use multi CPU to largely improve the speed of Keras LSMT

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to use multi CPU calculation to largely improve the speed of Keras LSMT. I have 150 CUPs and `htop` shows that I am using multi CPUs for calculation, but a little percentage of each CPU are used, therefore the final speed is still very slow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
jobs = 100 # it means number of cores
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=jobs*10,
                         inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                         allow_soft_placement=True,
                         log_device_placement=True,
                         device_count={'CPU': jobs})
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
K.get_session(session)
```

I trid

```
intra_op_parallelism_threads=0, 
inter_op_parallelism_threads=0
```

and

```
intra_op_parallelism_threads=job*10, 
inter_op_parallelism_threads=job*10
```

Both are slow.

Comment: Define slow, put numbers, LSTMs are difficult to parallelize due to sequential processing.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I mean compared with the time cost without `K.get_session(session)` . Actually, I found that even without above setting, multi CPUs are also used during the calculation, seems keras will automatically use multi CPUs.

Comment: Sorry but that made no sense to me, also you should be setting the session, not getting it (i.e. K.set_session)